# QGIS GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have some shapefiles and want to store them in a GeoPackage. Therefore I use the *save as* function for every layer. In the export dialog window I select the storage path and the name of my GeoPackage. QGIS uses automatically the name of my GeoPackage as layername and I have to change it.

Is there a way that QGIS uses automatically the layername of the data, which I want to export?

The *package layer* function has the problem that I can not change the coordinate reference system of my files.

Comment: Is the abbreviation KBS for kilobytes or something else?

Comment: I assume he refers to CRS, since KBS is the german abbreviation for coordinate reference system.

Comment: If you have many layers to save it might be faster to use the command line utility ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#ogr2ogr for the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package layers function in QGIS. You can find this in the processing toolbox. To change the CRS of your layers you need to have them loaded with QGIS and individually...

Right-click on your layer > properties > source > 'set source coordinate reference system'

[image]

Comment: But with this tool I can´t change the CRS of my data

Comment: Sorry Joe I forgot to explain that part! If you have your layers loaded into QGIS you can change the CRS before using the package layers tool. I've added this to the above.

Comment: If you change the CRS this way you're not reprojecting !!! that's a sure recipe for later problem...

Comment: @J.R how about explaining the correct way to do it then instead?

Comment: @ChrisJenner The correct way to change projection (by reprojecting) IS the "save as..." method , just changing the CRS in layer properties doesn't change anything to your layer but associate a wrong CRS with it. That will cause it to display in an erroneous location and not align with other data.